# Can I use VB.NET/object oriented languages to act as PL/SQL for SQL server

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, plsql

I am fairly new to DBA programming and am currently taking SQL programming. However, I was trying to figure out if it is really necessary to learn PL/SQL. I read that PL/SQL has procedures, condition statements, looping statements, etc. However, so does the other object oriented programming languages that invoke the data from the tables in the oracle server. Could I just use VB.NET to act as PL/SQL. I am also really not sure how SQL or PL/SQL statements work inside VB.NET/object oriented languages.

I know it can't be as simple as typing in VB.NET after the server connection is established:

> ### (SQL Statement)
>
> Select *
>   FROM emp;

Thanks for your help to a newbie :)

Comment: Yes, go read some books about SQL. You'll understand how it all pieces together later.

Comment: There are _many_ DB programming tutorials for VB.NET and SQL Server or Oracle, you should start reading them.

Comment: ignore PL/SQL at this stage... but find a good tutorial for SQL itself

Comment: I'm confused - you want to write database queries in VB?  Or you have SQL queries and want to _execute_ them from a VB app?  If you're querying an oracle database then yes, it's _critical_ to learn PL/SQL.  You should start with _standard_ SQL (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc.) but you will very soon fining that you need to use oracle-specific functions.

Comment: If you speak only Spanish and some other guy speaks only Mandarin, and you talk on the phone - do you really understand each other?

Comment: Thanks everyone on your input... I will look for tutorials and books for SQL. I have never included a query from Oracle into another programming language as VB.NET so was unsure if I should call a result from the table into VB.NET or write the SQL syntax that would contact the Oracle Server kind of like a javascript function built into HTML. Just wondered if standard SQL will work kind of the same way as PL/SQL. Sorry that this was off topic as I asked for materials... just didn't want you awesome programmers have to do so much work to explain how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely necessary to know PL/SQL in order to simply query an Oracle database. However, if you need to do more advanced things (e.g. creating triggers) you'll need to know PL/SQL because there's no support for triggers written in .Net languages. (Note that it's possible for triggers to invoke Java). 
I suggest that for now you should use what you're comfortable with and learn enough SQL to get along - then you can learn about more advanced topics, such as PL/SQL programming, when you need to.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you this was a very nice response Bob Jarvis. My major is not in Database Management so SQL is pretty intimidating right now with all the new different concepts. However, it is very interesting and once I have mastered this I will go to PL/SQL.

Comment: It *is* possible to [write stored procedures in .Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085095.html), although I doubt it's ever a good idea to do so.

Comment: @JonHeller - ah - I haven't seen 12c yet. Good to know. (At my place of (w)irk I figure we'll put 12c in about the time that 13x is end-of-lifetime'd :-)